# How do I fetch data from PHP link into TextView

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in programming.
I want my app to have a button and when it's pressed it will fetch data from my PHP link and display it on a TextView.
this is the link "http://sbms.atwebpages.com/SB/test.php?id=5" it should return the value 25,25 to the TextView.

I tried this "https://github.com/SumitRajpal/MySqlAndroid" but it didn't seem to work

Comment: what is the error of "didn't seem to work"?

Comment: This question is not related to PHP or MySQL in the sense that it should. The tags are misleading.

Comment: @PeteHouston it just doesn't show any result in the TextView

Comment: @AbdullahAlrubaysh what is your code?

Comment: @PeteHouston identical to this "https://github.com/SumitRajpal/MySqlAndroid" but I replaced the link with my link "http://sbms.atwebpages.com/SB/test.php?id=5"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could read these guidelines before asking a new question. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't show anything because you use someone else's project and get data from another URL that is in different format.

You have to update the code to make it works. It cannot work auto-magically!

Here the update part in the `MainActivity.java`

```
private void getSqlDetails() {

    String url= "http://sbms.atwebpages.com/SB/test.php?id=5";  <--- update your URL like this
    pd.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {    
                    result.setText(response);   <---- only one line here on this `onResponse` method
                }
```

There are two points I noted above, you can see.

Answer (score 0):

For any network-related actions you should use `HTTP` request API. I recommend these ones:

[`Retrofit`](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

[`OkHttp`](https://github.com/square/okhttp)

Fetch data from the server and set as text to your `textView` with `textView.setText(myServerData)`